# Resetting preferences when using PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android

I am loading a PreferenceScreen from an xml file to use as the screen to configure a new event so I'm attempting to clear and reset the values of the SharedPreference this activity is using. The problem I'm encountering is that when attempting to move to using a named preference manager, it seems the preference gets cleared but when I select an EditTextPreference element, the old data is still the default entered text on the popup.

In my onCreate method I'm attempting to initialize the preferences, clear them, then set to default values. My understanding from the dev resources were that there's no way to clear/reset in one step..

```
private static final String PREFNAME = "newmeetingactivity.preferences";

//load preferences and set name
addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.newmeeting_preferences);
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(PREFNAME);
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_PRIVATE);

//Clear the preferences 
_sharedPreferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = _sharedPreferences.edit();
ed.clear();
ed.commit();

//Load default preferences from file again
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, _sharedPreferences.toString() , MODE_PRIVATE, R.layout.newmeeting_preferences, true);
```

Edit: To try to better explain what I'm attempting to do (in case my approach is way off): I need to clear shared preferences used on a given activity while not interfering with the settings from other activities (as they should persist indefinitely).

Answer (score -1):

Could you instead try using the `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` to get your prefs.

Edit:

**adb shell** into your application after you choose to reset the values.  If you look at the preference file you will see that it's default value has been set.  Try refreshing your activity.  One way I did this was by simply killing it from the Applications menu.  When the activity restarts it will have the expected default value.

Comment: With this the other shared preferences (the ones meant to be permanent, such as user settings) get cleared as well.

Comment: Might be a ghetto solution, but you could implement your own kind clear function that just goes through and re-sets all the values to defaults that way.  This is really a quick and dirty solution, but you could always replace it with the proper code once you figure out how to do it later.